# Fast processing of large XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

I have a big XMLNode in VB.NET (we're talking 10s/100s of thousands of nodes, and millions of attributes).

The general structure of the XML is:

```
<other xml nodes></other xml nodes>
<list>
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    <item attr1="" attr2="" attr3="" attr4="" ... />
    .
    .
    .
</list>
```

What I want to do, is remove item nodes based upon certain attributes (say if I had 50,000 nodes, my criteria would probably delete 49500 of them).

The problem I have, is that it takes a few seconds for my code to remove such a large number of nodes, and I need it to go faster.

I've tried a few different ways of doing this, the fastest I've got todate is:

```
dim xnlList = xnBigXMLNode.selectNodes("//list/item[@attr1=sample]")
for each xnNode in xnlList
    xnNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnNode)
next
```

*Please forgive any mistakes in the above code, I'm not at my development machine at the moment

As an added constraint, I need to keep the "other xml nodes" in the xmlNode.

I've considered deleting the whole list, and adding back the nodes that I needed, but that took even longer to execute.

Can anybody think of a way to get this deleting thousands of nodes any faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a pretty huge file. Consider that NTFS allocation is not contiguous, and that the average random read speed of HDDs is less than 5MB/s. The hard disk may be your very bottleneck, rather than your code.

Comment: @GiulioFranco I'm actually getting the XML from a webservice, but stepping through the code, it's apparent that there are a few bottle necks - one is getting the xml from the webservice, the other is the deleting of such a large number of nodes.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Looking at how you wrote the example structure, the xml seems quite simple in its structure. Even if that would be hardly maintainable, have you considered using plaintext/regexp matching on the plaintext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution that takes milliseconds to run (as opposed to the few seconds it took before).

It turns out that:

```
dim xnlList = xnBigXMLNode.selectNodes("//list/item[@attr1=sample]")
for each xnNode in xnlList
    xnNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnNode)
next
```

takes a few seconds to run, whereas:

```
dim xnlList = xnBigXMLNode.selectNodes("//list/item")
for each xnNode in xnlList
    xnNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xnNode)
next
```

takes milliseconds.

So inside my loop I wrote code to test each node for the required attributes, and deleted appropriately.

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic case for writing a SAX filter. The parser generates SAX events and passes them to your application, your application passes a subset of the events on to a serializer, which generates the new XML file. No need to build a tree in memory.

I don't know the details of how to do this in VB, being a Java man, but the technology certainly exists.

Comment: I C# there is `XMLReader` which is a STaX parser. It's similar, but it's a pull parser, rather than a push parser (the difference is that it's the user that drives the parsing, rather than the parser calling methods on an interface)

Comment: Yes, you can also use a pull parser. Personally, I find that for a simple filter like this, the push approach is simpler, but many programmers are more comfortable writing the part of the program that owns the main control loop.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for the answer, I'd considered writing my own parser, but I'll have a look up of SAX style parsers for .net

Comment: If you can, I think it would be good to perform xml parsing  concurrently with the fetching. Since I/O is slower than CPU, the time your CPU takes to parse the XML would be totally hidden by network latencies.